# What does the dm in sysdm.cpl stand for?

Tags: windows, control-panel

I know running it opens up Advanced System Properties but unlike most Microsoft commands that have a logic to the name I can't figure out what this one stands for.

Does anybody know what the **dm** in **sysdm.cpl** stands for?

Comment: I believe that DM stands for Device Manager.

Comment: Some think its system admin.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Whilst I cannot provide a source, I would assume it stands for System Device Manager.

The Device Manager has a menu of its own now, however in older versions of Windows the System properties menu had far fewer features and the Device Manager had a tab of its own within the properties menu rather than its own menu.

Windows 98 properties menu's device manager tab:

[image]

Comment: Thanks to this answer I've found the original reference in the windows 95 version of the applet. I've updated my originally wrong stack overflow answer from 2015: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29726171/in-windows-os-sysdm-cpl-what-dm-stands-for/31091102#31091102